# How to pass a dynamic object from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I need a Partial View with a some dynamic input fields. To do this, my model contains an object of type "object", and then in my controller I create a new model with the related object type "myobject".

All works fine in the PartialViewResult, but after the form submit the object does not contain my object type "myobject".

How to send in the form submit the correct object?

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult mypage()
{
myModel model = new myModel();
myObject obj = new myObject();
model.myobject = obj;

return PartialView(“mypage”,model);
}

public PartialViewResult Save (myModel model)
{
    // Here I need model.myobject!!!
}
```

Model:

```
public class myModel
{
    public long id {get;set;}
    public object myobject {get;set;}
}

public myObject
{
    public string myname {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model myModel
// form (code omitted)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myobject)

<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Template

```
@model myObject

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Object itself won't have any properties - you'd need to cast it to the type containing the property you require.

If you can't do that because you want to reuse the view for different myobject types, then you'll need to use an interface and some commonly named properties.

The alternative is to use a property bag i.e. a dictionary and reference the value by key name in the view.

You can then have a property defined on your model:

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> MyItems {get;set;}
```

and reference them in your Page:

```
 model.MyItems["keyName"]
```

Comment: I've tried to cast but I get this error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'MyProjext.Models.myObject'."

Comment: Where did you try to cast it? - can you modify your code to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the object returned.
It's something like that:

```
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) objectReturned;
```

Comment: I've tried to cast but I get this error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'MyProjext.Models.myObject'."